# Vector subscript out of range?

Tags: c++, vector

I am making my own programming language (for learning) and I have error.

```
Debug Assertion Failed!
Program: C:/Path/MSVCP140D.dll
Line: 1232

Expression vector subscript out of range

For information how your progr... (Not important)
```

function that make error:

```
Parser::Parser(std::vector<std::string> toks) {
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < toks.size(); i++) {
        if (toks[i++] + " " + toks[i] == "PRINT STRING:") { 
            std::cout << toks[i += 1] << std::endl;
        }

        if (toks[i++] + " " + toks[i] == "ASM STRING:") {
            std::cout << "FOUND ASM" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

function that generate toks:

```
Lexer::Lexer(std::string source){
    std::string tok = "";
    std::string string = "";
    int state = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= source.length(); i++) {
        tok += source[i];

        if (tok == " ") {
            if (state == 1) {
                string += tok;
            } else tok = "";
        } else if (tok == "\n") {
            tok = "";
        } else if (tok == "print") {
            tokens.push_back("PRINT");
            tok = "";
        } else if (tok == "asm") {
            tokens.push_back("ASM");
            tok = "";
        } else if (tok == "\"") {
            if (state == 0) {
                state = 1;
            } else if (state == 1) {
                tokens.push_back("STRING:");
                tokens.push_back(string);
                string = "";
                state = 0;
                tok = "";
            }
        } else if (state == 1) {
            string += source[i];
            tok = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
toks that are generated: PRINTSTRING:print  expASMSTRING:ams  exp
toks one by one:
PRINT
STRING:
print exp
ASM
STRING:
ams exp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the only time you want to increment `i` is here:

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < toks.size(); i++)
//                                    ^^^
```

`toks[i++]` and then `toks[i]` in the loop without a check will turn out very bad. Should it be `toks[i + 1]`, keeping in mind `i + 1` can't reach `toks.size()`? Same for this: `toks[i += 1]`.

Maybe you should have stuff like `toks[i]`,`toks[i + 1]`, `toks[i + 2]` in the body of the loop and this:

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i + 2 < toks.size(); i += 3)
```

And another problem is:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= source.length(); i++)
//                ^^
//           should be <
```

I don't know if that's all.

Comment: I change it, and still the same :/

Comment: @pyDzoni I can't help you without MCVE. This is all I could see. Frankly, you have luck this is not closed yet and that you have this partial answer.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I did't see i + 2